# Unable to replace bools with ints

Tags: c#

I have sql strings such as the following, with several `Trues` and `Falses`:

```
INSERT INTO SystemRules (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) 
Values (False,False,True,False,False)
```

I want to replace all False with 0 and all True with 1. But when I try this:

```
sql = sql.Replace(",True,", ",1,").Replace(",True)", ",1)").Replace(",False,", ",0,").Replace(",False)", ",0)");
```

...it only removes ***some*** of the Falses...not all of them. For example, I end up with this:

```
INSERT INTO SystemRules (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) 
Values (0,False,1,0,False)
```

What I expected was this:

```
INSERT INTO SystemRules (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5) 
Values (0,0,1,0,0)
```

So then I try regex instead (showing just 1 piece below):

```
sql = Regex.Replace(sql, ",True)", ",1)");
```

That particular line blows up with this error: `parsing ",True)" - Too many )'s.`

What is the most efficient way to replace all Trues and Falses in a sql statement with 1s and 0s? I have always found string.Replace() in c# to replace globally, I'm baffled as to why it's missing some. There are no spaces in there, I have triple-checked. One proof of this is that if I run the series of REPLACEs above a 2nd time, it *does replace the stragglers*. Why not the first time? Is c# `replace` really not global? Thank you.

Comment: Why not do it during the SQL building `col1Value?1:0` or `col1Value == "True"?1:0`

Comment: I don't know how it replaced the first `False` with `0` even, since none of your `.Replace()` arguments allows for `False` without a prepended comma.

Comment: An attempt to reproduce your issue does not produce the result you describe. Your description of the problem is not accurate: http://ideone.com/FzUE6c

Comment: Your repro is invalid. Also, you're accounting for when the word is inbetween commas, or is at the end and only has a preceding comma, but you aren't taking into account when the word is at the start, and only has a receding comma.  Also, why bother with the bloody commas at all?

Comment: How are you generating this string in the first place?  Couldn't you replace the 0's and 1's at generation time rather than afterwards?  Or even better use a parameterized SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error with `Regex.Replace` because `)` is a metacharacter that needs to be escaped. Placing a backspace (two backspaces for regular C# string) will address this problem:

```
sql = Regex.Replace(sql, ",True\\)", ",1\\)");
```

You can simplify comma/parentheses handling with `\\b` anchor:

```
sql = Regex.Replace(sql, "\\bTrue\\b", "1");
```

However, manipulating SQL as a string is a very dangerous idea ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/335858)). You should refactor your code to use parameterized SQL instead ([how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/335858)).

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry about sql injection, this is a back office app with no user input going into it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put Regex or ",True," 
It can be done in a very simple way

```
 string s="INSERT INTO SystemRules (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)Values (False,False,True,False,False)";
        s=s.Replace("False", "0").Replace("True", "1");
```